# Hide a question's real score from users for some time so that they can't tell that it has downvotes

Tags: feature-request, downvotes, voting

Recently there have been some very lengthy discussion threads on metaSO on downvoting. Askers have really concerns about downvoting. At the same time downvoters support their stand by saying *downvoting is essential to maintain quality of this site*. There are various solutions suggested on this problem. Both, short term and long term, complex and simple solutions.

**The main disadvantage of making votes immediately visible is, it could possibly make experts prejudiced about the question by looking at its vote score.** Especially if its downvoted they may think '*Why should I bother? It's already been downvoted*' Thus questioner and (future viewers as well) could miss few more good answers/comments to their question. Also, having less experts have visited, the question will not have accurate score.

**As an simple and quick solution, can we please hide question's real score for some time so that they can't see it has downvotes ?**

If clicked on up or downvote button, SO might want to display message similar to ***'Thanks for your vote. It will be visible after XXX time.'*** (Now the correct time limit needs to be decided, weather its good to hide score for 2 hours or 2 days etc. But I guess those all are implementation details and development experts at SO are best to decide on those details)

This way, we'll have maximum users visit the question and thus score of a post can be made more accurate as we'll have more people reviewed it.

(Just my two cents in solving this big issue)

Comment: Saving experts time by letting them avoid low quality questions is not a "disadvantage" of down voting.

Comment: It's not clear who you want to display downvotes to, and why. If a question has a negative score, ***everyone*** already knows that it has at least 1 downvote. Furthermore, users with 1000 rep or more [can choose to see exact vote counts](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user), if they wish.

Comment: How about letting experts decide on the quality of question on their own, rather than making them prejudiced by displaying votes?

Comment: @Andrew what if an expert is the first person who downvotes the question, thereby saving other experts the trouble of also having to view the question?

Comment: @Andrew are you trying to ***hide downvotes from "experts"?*** Is that what your feature-request is? If so, **then it's not going to happen.** The whole point of voting is to save other people time and effort by very quickly signaling, with a reasonable degree of accuracy, how well-written a question is, so that users don't have to waste time on poorly written questions.

Comment: @Cupcake Downvote will save a minute of other expert but at the same time it prevents few more good answers as well. What is trade off here?

Comment: @Andrew what kind of "good answers" do you expect to come out of ***a bad question?*** More often than not, bad questions do not have great answers that benefit anyone other than the original asker of the question.

Comment: *What is the tradeoff here?* Trading off answering a poor question in favor of answering a good one. Time is finite. Keep in mind that no one's *forcing* experts to disregard downvoted questions - downvotes are signposts.

Comment: @Cupcake There are many questions on SO which have been downvoted but their answers have got lots of upvotes.

Comment: @Andrew just because an answer has a lot of upvotes, it doesn't necessarily mean that it's ***a great answer,*** that it's ***a useful answer,*** only that it's ***a correct answer.*** In fact, on bad questions, **that's exactly what upvotes mean.** Bad questions, for the most post, do not encourage *great answers*. *No one is going to benefit from those types of answers* other than the question poster.

Comment: [main] is not a help-forum. It's a Question and Answer site, and is meant to help **a lot** of people, not just one.

Comment: All I know is, we are although not forcing but definitely making other expert to think in prejudiced manner about a question and thus preventing few more answers, at the cost of saving few seconds of theirs. I am not saying not to downvote. But I honestly don't think displaying downvotes after some time will bring down the SO business. It will rather help.

Comment: @Andrew what makes you think that an expert will want to answer a bad question, whether they can see the downvotes on it or not? Even if they can't see the downvotes, they'll clearly be able to tell ***from the question itself*** whether or not it's worth their time answering (if it's bad, the answer is almost-always **No**). Displaying a score immediately just saves them the time to pass on it.

Comment: @Andrew: I'm not a sheep.  I don't ignore a question because someone else downvoted it.  I ignore it because *it's not a good question*.  The downvotes are just a symptom of the same problem that causes questions to be ignored and/or closed.

Comment: @Andrew stick around on Meta a little while. Read the questions that other people have asked. Learn how [main] works. Read the [Stack Exchange blog posts](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/05/stack-exchange-for-iphone-is-here/). Read [Jeff Atwood's blog posts about Stack Overflow](http://blog.codinghorror.com/how-to-write-without-writing/) (he has many). Read [Joel's post about Stack Overflow's launch](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2008/09/15.html). Then you'll understand why everything works the way it does.

Comment: 'Quality' is perception. A question on science might be 'bad quality' for a scientist working in NASA at the same time for a teacher teaching in small school it could be a good quality question. But why the scientist would want to shout and tell everyone (including the teacher) that the question is bad and that its not worth to read through ?

Comment: It sounds like you're against downvotes entirely, Andrew - you seem to argue against the very reason they're here. Valid position, though you'd find a lot of opposition against it.

Comment: @Andrew: Because he believes that.  And there's probably truth to it.  Questions don't typically get downvoted because of not-quite-perfect grammar or a misspelled word here or there.  There are usually fundamental problems with either it or the way it was asked.

Comment: @Andrew the quality of a question **is not relative.** ***A bad question is a bad question, period, no matter who is reading it.*** Also, ["Stack Overflow is a question and answer site ***for professional and enthusiast programmers.***"](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). It's a site ***for experts.*** This is not a help-forum for [help-vampires](http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/) who ask basic questions that could have been solved on their own if they had put a little more effort into the problem themselves first.

Comment: I do not see the votes on this question.  Is it a bug or a feature?

Comment: @Andrew by your analogy, ***[main] is NASA, full of rocket scientists!***

Comment: Wrong! Quality (of anything) is always a perception. It's relative concept. And yes, 'Stack Overflow is for professional and enthusiasts' not only for those who think they are rocket scientists.

Comment: @Andrew if you want to go ask questions on a Question and Answer site ***that doesn't vote on questions,*** then I recommend that you ask them on [Quora](https://www.quora.com/) instead. Or heck, just go to ***an actual forum*** somewhere and ask your question.

Comment: Out of all the arguments that one could have with another person over [main]'s methods, at least this one is still relatively polite `:)`

Comment: @Cupcake: I never said I am against downvoting. All I am saying is we should display downvotes after some time. Can we see 'dislike' option on Facebook? Those who dislike post, stays just silent. Look how much popular the site is. But since this is QA site, rather than keeping dislikers (experts) silent, I am only asking to display their opinion after some time. Thats it!

Comment: @Andrew:  SO is not Facebook.  We have upvotes *and* downvotes.  And we expect both to count for something.  (Just so it's said, though, you know how many times i've gotten annoyed over Facebook's lack of a "dislike" button?)

Comment: Had they (Facebook) provided 'dislike' option, I am pretty sure they would not have been at par with the popularity what they are having now. There is serious thought process involved behind not having 'dislike' option :)

Comment: @Andrew And there is serious thought process involved in having a downvote button here...Facebook can do what they want, I don't understand why you'd think that's relevant to a programming Q+A site.

Answer (score 24):

There's a pretty serious flaw with this suggestion.  Consider what would happen if we implement this idea, then i cast a downvote on a new question.

What should the next person visiting the question see?

- If they see nothing, they'd know there's something weird about the votes on that question -- and a quick trip over to mSO would explain it.  So now someone knows *anyway* that the question has been downvoted, and you've gained nothing -- but given up the ability to show that it's only been downvoted once.  (And no, before you even go there: a "hide/show votes" box for the question's owner will never happen.)
- If they see 0, the system is *flat-out lying*.  It's rather like stuffing a ballot box, and the voting system itself starts to feel a bit shady.

I understand not liking downvotes.  But they happen, and they usually happen for a reason.  And it's pretty myopic to make the site lie to users because you want more "experts" answering a question despite someone already finding issues with it.

The more likely outcome will simply be more downvotes on the question, from the people who would have skipped over it had you not convinced SO to trick them into reading it.  Or from those who would have abstained or even upvoted if they could see when a question had already taken "enough" or "too much" punishment, respectively.

Comment: Your point about getting more downvotes is ***so true!*** That's exactly what would happen! Then the original poster will get question-banned ***very quickly***, so everyone ends up losing anyways `:P`

Answer (score 11):

Let's accept this premise at face value:

> The main disadvantage of downvoting is, it demotivates experts from looking at the question by thinking 'its already been downvoted'.

So instead of letting them see that a question has been downvoted, which they would skip (because they are demotivated), they'll see a question with a score of 0, which they'll look at (because they are not demotivated). So they check the question out and find that it is an absolute piece of crap. They downvote and perhaps vote to close. Oh, and they'll notice **immediately** that their downvote has no immediate effect on the total score of the question. How motivating! And they move on to another question which was downvoted but whose real score is still invisible.

**This way of doing things would have the net effect of demotivating experts from coming to the site at all.**

Comment: "it is an absolute piece of crap" or may be they find that it is absolute great? (perception is relative, you see). "Their downvote has no immediate effect on the total score of the question" obviously yes. But why it would demotivate them? Because once its implemented and documented, may be SO can display relevant message after voting that the score is going to visible after two days. Still by downvoting or upvoting they can do their duty.

Comment: @Andrew, the one who has *duties* is the questioner. And failing on them translates into downvotes that are real-time feedback for everybody. No, but thanks, your proposal is flawed.

Comment: @Andrew it sounds like you want people to look at questions that ***might be OK***. Maybe it has some downvotes, but maybe it's decent enough to get a few upvotes too, if only enough people look at it. **We don't want questions that might be OK. We want great questions that are unambiguously great**. Write good questions. Questions are often downvoted because they're poorly written, so just write well-written, well-researched questions.

Comment: @Andrew so you didn't really explain it clearly and honestly up-front in your original question, but it sounds like you want to do something like temporarily hiding a question score, [like what reddit does](http://www.reddit.com/wiki/faq#wiki_why_does_a_dot_sometimes_show_up_where_the_score_should_be.3F).

Comment: @Andrew Reddit does this for a different purpose than what your goal is: reddit wants to stop mass-sheep voting (["the bandwagon effect"](http://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/comments/1dfnku/why_are_comment_scores_hidden/)), you want more people to look at a post and score it more accurately, we want to avoid people having to look at posts altogether. An argument can be made that the score of a post can be made more accurate by having more people review it, but please note that that is a very different goal from why we even have post scores and votes in the first place.

Comment: @Cupcake: "score of a post can be made more accurate by having more people review it" yes that's precisely is my stand behind posting this question. If SO has different goal altogether in having votes, that's perfect. Please can you post this as an answer so that I can accept. Will be probably helpful for those who come here in future.

Comment: @Andrew what I posted isn't really good enough to be an answer, I'm just going to leave it as a comment. If you want to revise your question to be clearer about what you're trying to propose, then maybe we can have a more productive conversation about it. Or, if you give me a few days, I can help you revise your question (as best as I can).

Comment: @Cupcake: Many thanks for positive consideration towards the question. Just now I've edited the question and have tried explaining and making the point more clear. I have't now emphasized on downvote as it could jeopardize the discussion. So I've made it generic for 'voting' as such. Please feel free to edit if you think something is still not clear/elaborated.

Comment: @Andrew I'm sorry, but I'm just not going to have time to devote to this anymore. You're on your own. If you want people to take your proposal more seriously next time, you need to be ***completely honest*** about what it is that you're trying to do. If you have a friend who can write English very well, have him or her review your question before posting it next time, not so much for minor grammar and punctuation issues, but for how well you expressed your idea in the first place. It will help a lot next time.

Comment: @Cupcake: It's not about honesty. Its mostly because I just didn't given complete thought about it before I post. More I had focused on only from downvote perspective. But later (after getting comments here) I realized its better if overall voting could be hidden for some time (till the question gets enough visibility).

Comment: @Andrew OK, I believe you. You could try to make another feature request proposing the new idea, but you need to make your argument clearly, because you should expect strong opposition to it at first. Back up your argument by pointing out how Reddit hides votes temporarily to prevent mass sheep voting. Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way to address the previous answers' concern  and OP's proposal is to hide the score from **only the asker** for a few days.

The concerns like *demotivating experts from coming to the site* and *What should the next person visiting the question see?* are not valid as the content rating/voting system is in place and viewable by experts and the others(say, with a minimum rep of 105).

This also addresses concerns like

> **Leaving a comment accompanying a downvote can lead to negative consequences, like revenge downvoting and even off-site harassment**.

**Comment system and Voting system Independence**: Because the vote is only provided to  the asker after a few days, the comment won't be tied to the vote by time(OP won't be able to guess the downvoter just from the commented time).

- Comments form a system of providing voluntary feedback to the poster and
- Voting form a system of providing voluntary feedback to future readers

They don't mix.