# Can we hide votes until we reach a threshold?

Tags: feature-request

I feel like once something is down voted once, people bandwagon down-vote and don't give the question/answer its fair try.  To mitigate this effect we should hide its current vote status until the community has had a chance to properly evaluate it.

Take the example of a question with a single up/down vote.  At this point, the community doesn't have strong support one way or the other.  Yet on the screen it will immediately impose a cognitive bias to the next reader once they see its already negative/positive, when at least initially they should approach the question on its own merits and comments (If the comments are legit).

You might argue that any voting mechanism would impose a bias to the next reader, and that in fact that is the voting mechanism's intention!  This is true.  Which is why I would only suggest it for young questions for which the community doesn't have a strong opinion about its merit.  The voting mechanism should be used when looking through SO, but a question with a single vote should probably be approached differently than a question with thousands of votes.

I would suspect that this would have more of an impact on the negative votes than the positive... but its just a suspicion.

Edit #1: Compare/contrast with [Hide a question's real score from users for some time so that they can't tell that it has downvotes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254121/hide-a-questions-real-score-from-users-for-some-time-so-that-they-cant-tell-th)

This post has a very similar idea as the one i presented.  However, he suggests a slightly different implementation and gives different supporting arguments.  The main difference is that I would like the community to have a settled opinion about the matter before broadcasting it which he doesn't mention at all.  I do agree with some of his points, but I propose a modification to the voting system that would still be in line with the spirit of a rating system without it being too fickle.  He also fails to mention that its an actual scientific,  measurable, effect that seeing an initial positive/negative rating will bias you.  Unfortunately he mentioned experts as his case, when i think it would be the more inexperienced users that would be susceptible to this.  (although all humans are susceptible)

Answer (score 14):

An important bit for votes is that they are a signal for people answering the question that its crap (or not).

By hiding the votes until some threshold a person doesn't necessarily know that a given question is good or bad until some time later.  By down voting questions that are bad early, they signal to people "this question needs more work before it can get a good answer" and "if you spend time writing an answer now, it may be for naught if/when the question is deleted"

These signals are especially important to new users who don't know what makes for a good question on Stack Overflow.  This is doubly important when you come to the front page and wouldn't see votes on many things... "if I ask a question like this one, will I get rep? or not?"

Showing the score immediately is a key part of quickly separating the wheat from the chaff... and lets face it, Stack Overflow gets *way* too much chaff.

Don't make people waste their time trying to figure out if something is good or bad when the community is already trying to do so.

Comment: Is there a way to convert this to a more discussion like thread?  I feel like either you missed my points or i just didn't convey them clearly enough.  This seems like an overview of why we need a voting system on SO in general, without addressing any reasons i mentioned for modifying it.

Comment: @CarlosBribiescas You can always stop into chat.  I'm often in the Whiteboard of Programmers.SE.  A key point to consider though - I *want* to be biased about a question when I consider if I should answer it or not.  Also, give [Podcast #59](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/05/podcast-59-hes-one-of-those-science-ists/) a listen and consider how important up votes and down votes are for information about if its a good question or not and if I should pay time reading it.

Comment: Dumb comment.  Can you post a link to that room?

Comment: @CarlosBribiescas [The Whiteboard](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/21/the-whiteboard).  Yep, its the info page rather than the direct link so that people don't join it just by clicking random links.  Note that we're primarily a workday crowd as the chat is on our other monitor while at work... it can get quiet on the weekends and evenings there though often people are still around... just not active about it.