# Meta on Meta: when to change a discussion question to a feature-request?

Tags: discussion, support, meta

There are some [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) posts on Meta which are answered with close to unanimous highly-supported feature requests.

The one that triggered this question is: [Can we make it more obvious to new users that downvotes on the main site are not insults and in fact can help them help themselves?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366889/can-we-make-it-more-obvious-to-new-users-that-downvotes-on-the-main-site-are-not)

The question is +152/-8. The top answer is +254/-2. The second, similar, answer is +134/-8. The community's response is pretty clear.

What should be done to get an official response on these requests? Should I post a new Meta labeling it with [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) and referencing the post? Should I add [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) to that Q&A?

Lately on Meta there has been voiced concern about SO not *listening* to regular users. But maybe we aren't communicating in a way which encourages response from the powers that be.

Or, if the powers *are* listening and think it's a *bad* idea, can't they *drop a line* so we don't feel we are wasting our time?

Comment: The powers-that-be are generally swamped with work, I think. There was a push to make their development pipeline more transparent but that effort has stalled again.

Comment: _"Should I add [feature-request] to that Q&A?"_ No I don't think so, the question itself isn't really a clear feature-request. I think, for this case, the best thing to do is post a new feature-request with that top-voted answer. That would make for a very clear and specific question (in my eyes).

Comment: @AndréKool, I had the same idea. Except someone will come along and mark as a duplicate (have seen it happen before, will happen again). But, really, as Martijn alludes to, I would appreciate transparency as to the process. Even if it's "pipeline stalled for 6 months", at least *we know*.

Comment: @jpp We have reopen votes for that. Clearly specify you don't want to discuss the general point but want the feature to be implemented, and you will at least have my reopen votes when someone dupe-slams that with a discussion post.

Comment: Yup, even knowing something like: _"This is nr 32656 on our list and planned for 2065"_ or _"We won't implement this because..."_ would be nice to hear for a change. And what Erik said.

Comment: You should probably post an angry tweet about the subject...

Comment: wrt *official response on these request* see the MSE discussion: [Can we have a guaranteed pipeline for responses from Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263662/can-we-have-a-guaranteed-pipeline-for-responses-from-stack-exchange) (tl;dc status-declined)

Comment: @rene, Also, I feel a bit maligned the answer implies our efforts are wasted *because* we represent "only 10% of the user base". What happened to judging on content?

Comment: We happen to be the 10% that brings 90% to the table. Oh well.

Comment: There's a post somewhere where it says that even the powers that be don't take meta in consideration, cause it's too negative. That makes me.... Feel like the whole 'stack is built by the community' be a thing of the past. They want business and traffic now, and don't really care about the core groups of curators who want to maintain the site the way it was intended to be...

Comment: @jpp fully agree with you. Reading this made me very discouraged about the way this site is evolving :/....

Comment: @Patrice when was the last time the company did something the community wanted? The last and only one I can think of (except for design bikeshedding and easy bugs) was introducing chatroom timeouts for room owners, a feature that was already implemented for mods and was extended for room owners. I'm not sure there are many (any?) other examples where any change of substance was affected by community consensus.

Comment: Yup, dupe hammer is another example. It came [4 years ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230865/increase-close-vote-weight-for-gold-tag-badge-holders), and has been one of the most important tools in maintaining site quality. Similarly kickbans and timeouts in chat have proven paramount to moderating the site. The community has been begging for long years in various feature requests, not for the company to moderate the site but just to _enable_ the community to moderate themselves. These are the rare exceptions that made it through.

Comment: @AndrasDeak well they did shut down documentation

Comment: ["There is no doubt we've stopped making changes for core users..."](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314089/what-does-constructive-criticism-of-a-design-change-look-like/314348?noredirect=1#comment1030131_314348) <--- kind of explains what you observed

Comment: @gnat, True. What's left this community in limbo is the lack of clarity. Such a clear change in focus from 4 years ago deserves an explicit blog post, not a mere *comment*.

Comment: @jpp if you've been following recent major projects, feedback given, and how the company handled said projects in the face of feedback and occasionally overwhelming pushback (such as "teams", "documentation", "mentorship project", "welcome wagon", "new design"; take your pick) it's been pretty obvious since I started here 3 years ago that the community has been given [the back seat](https://media.giphy.com/media/rZLGH32X4Ei0o/giphy.gif).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I need to say that it's our responsibility to read and care about each post either way. I can't and won't absolve us of that in the process of agreeing with you that the real world matters while we reach the ideal one.

I would *not* change tags. I'd create a *separate* [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) that *links* to the discussion, and distills out all of the points where there was consensus, and highlights places where things might depend on the implementation.

Why? Because we're trying to get better at building things that make *sure* we see stuff, and I can quickly imagine bugs in ad-hoc stuff the community growth team has been building ourselves to help manage this causing something to fall through the cracks.

We're also working much closer with DAG, who has been piping stuff from meta into VSTS (there's a human triage component there), and until that process is way less fragile and rube-goldberg-ish, just open a new post (we've got plenty of room in the DB).

What we need to be able to do is give folks an actual SLA that fits well with you, *and* that isn't too scary for us in the process, and that's something we're working behind the scenes to do.

This is also, incidentally, a really helpful discussion and thanks for raising  it, something like it was on my next-month radar and this helps jumpstart upcoming initiatives.

Comment: I would love to see more things like SLAs and less things like [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314089/what-does-constructive-criticism-of-a-design-change-look-like/314348?noredirect=1#comment1030131_314348).

Answer (score 5):

In my opinion, you should only change questions tagged [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) to [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) if it is clearly and explicitly a request for a specific new feature.

Otherwise, the question should stay tagged as [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) for several reasons:

1. The body of the post likely is written in a way that doesn't lend itself well to a feature-request. In the case of the question you linked to, it is asking whether we *can* do something and if so, *how* would we do it. It wraps up with a call to action to the community. Questions tagged [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) should clearly request a new function on the site or a change to an existing one.
2. If the OP wanted to request something, they likely would have added that tag, instead. Remember, when asking a question you are prompted to pick at least one from [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion), [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request), [bug](/questions/tagged/bug), or [support](/questions/tagged/support), so there is a reasonable expectation of askers to be aware of those tags' existence.
3. Great [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) questions usually have an existing [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) behind them to back up their request. This is something that I think Shog taught me; if you have a feature request... that's great, and it may get implemented or it may get ignored or declined. If you have a feature request backed up by a [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) question with a score of +300/-5 (for example), it becomes a lot more solid and more difficult for moderators/developers to say "no we shouldn't do this".

Comment: I'd love to see the current official stance on #3.

Comment: @AndrasDeak Tim Post's answer above sort of covers this.

Comment: I'm not so sure about that. It tells us to do this and this to popular discussion posts that can give rise to spin-off feature requests. It doesn't say anything about whether feature requests (these spin-offs or the wealth of existing, community-supported ones) will be acted on any differently than we've seen these past years.

Comment: @AndrasDeak, You're right, I think my premise is wrong. There's no indication that the *wrong way/tag* is the *cause* of no response. But I'm equally happy that we have a commitment of sorts to at least address process and *attempt* to reopen communication channels. Nothing will change overnight. But I, for one, won't be reading/posting feature requests until I *see* change. Others may be more hopeful.

Comment: @AndrasDeak - Semi official: "by posting here, you're stepping up on a very large soapbox, in the middle of a very large crowd of very busy people... And as nice as we might all be as individuals, you're taking time away from something else we were planning on doing. We'd like to know you're not wasting it." -https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/272617/

Answer (score -4):

First off, to answer the titular question here of "when to change a discussion question to a feature request" is essentially never, *unless it was just asked* and is clearly a feature request instead of a discussion. If you would like to create a feature request, then ask that question; if you would like to create a discussion, then ask that question.

In order to create a new feature that changes an aspect of a large piece of legacy software like Stack Overflow maintains, you absolutely must provide evidence and material supporting your case. As a result of that being the situation, often feature requests are preempted with a fact finding and community consensus discussion. It is rare that actual features are implemented *solely* as the result of discussions.

The discussion you cite is not a fully fledged feature request, and neither is the answer you cite as the reason it should be. Robert Harvey is a very respected user here, but even he says that a solution with "any chance of succeeding" would look like his suggestion. Note the lack of definition in chance, or what success would be measured with.

Successful feature requests need to be backed with rigor, not with votes that indicate it would be nice if something were done. It is easy to sit around and point fingers at problems, but proposing solutions backed by evidence and rigor is how problems actually get solved.

Make no mistake, the Stack Overflow team reads *all* of these. I am sure they voted on the question you cite, and countless others. That doesn't mean they know what the solution is to each and every problem they observe, nor that their vote is somehow binding in agreement to implement suggested *directions* to solve problems. If there was a well researched, rigorous, suggestion which solved a problem without dispute and had clearly defined beneficial outcomes, they would implement it 6 times out of 8 weeks.

If you are still legitimately curious about the process of feature requests, please see [*"The challenges of persuading a large, critical audience"* by Shog9](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/272617/1026459), it is excellent.

As for the team not listening, let's just look at some of last month's highly upvoted feature requests on Meta Stack Exchange. Here are some which were responded to by the team where they were implemented or are planned on being implemented:

- [Can we show new/anonymous users more Q&A?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314134/can-we-show-new-anonymous-users-more-qa)
- [Please wrap the entire comment flag description in a `<label>` (making the entire text clickable)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/313454/please-wrap-the-entire-comment-flag-description-in-a-label-making-the-entir)
- [Make the comment flag dialog draggable again](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/313631/make-the-comment-flag-dialog-draggable-again)
- [Why was a vertical line added on the left for users who collapse the left navigation? Can it please be removed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/313930/why-was-a-vertical-line-added-on-the-left-for-users-who-collapse-the-left-naviga)
- [Prevent users from immediately deleting their accounts if they've made one post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314617/prevent-users-from-immediately-deleting-their-accounts-if-theyve-made-one-post)
- [Badge suggestion: Can we get a "Decade" badge for being an active member for 10 years?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314466/badge-suggestion-can-we-get-a-decade-badge-for-being-an-active-member-for-10)

I am sure more research with regards to feature requests from the community being planned or completed beyond one month will also yield even more results.

Comment: The [other side](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request+-status-planned+-status-completed?sort=votes&pagesize=50) is worth a read too.

Comment: @AndrasDeak - Note you forgot to include tags of review or declined in your search. You also included negatively voted posts, are those indicative of the team needing to spend their time on? As well, you seem to include posts which were answered by a team member, such as this one: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/314794/178816. Perhaps you should redefine your search of "the other side", because it contains numerous and egregious errors.

Comment: You're right, we're probably talking about two different things. Your point is probably that the team is actively responding to popular feature requests. Mine is that even popular feature requests tend to go nowhere.

Comment: @AndrasDeak - Popular feature requests are often not backed by anything aside from an agreement that there is a problem which needs to be fixed, because a vast majority of feature requests read as "it would be nice if we could do something along the lines of", and then go off to suggest something that could maybe be done which could solve part of the problem without addressing the impact of only partially solving, or addressing what impact that partial solution may incur as well. Popularity has no correlation to quality, which is why many popular topics are banned at Stack Overflow.

Comment: I read @Shog9's [The challenges of persuading a large, critical audience](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/272617/1026459), can see the problem. But none of us are in that meeting room. We don't know who runs the show, what buttons to push, what compromises to make. Neither do we have access to the SO back-end technology to determine what's viable or impossible. Your requirements suggest [this new feature request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/373477/display-a-message-to-a-user-the-first-time-they-receive-a-downvote) should be auto-dismissed. The bar you've set is far too high.

Comment: @jpp - You don't have to be in the room to understand the majority of factors that play into these types of decisions. All you need is experience with making high impact decisions, and the understanding that there are consequences. As a result, it is of utmost importance to consider the downsides, and *be very specific* when outlining changes, as well as when outlining side effects and expected outcomes.

Comment: You entirely do have access to the SO back-end technology. It is all outlined here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10369/178816

Comment: That suggested feature could use some more fleshing out, but it is at least a feature request. The previous discussion it setup (which I closed as a duplicate) had been had before, but at least it attempted to get some facts and community response prior to posting. It does even have some support in different ways from team members. I don't think it should be auto-dismissed, I am merely stating the bar for auto-accept, which is ridiculously high. The gray middle ground of review, planned, completed, is the normal path, and you very well may see that happen. It just takes time and patience.