# Reward good questions by new contributors instead of punishing bad ones

Tags: feature-request, downvotes, new-users, new-contributor-indicator

I feel that new contributors are often treated a bit harshly on SO. We have all seen the 'Hi, welcome to SO. Here's why your question is bad', accompanied by lots of downvotes and in some cases some sarcasm on the side.

I feel that a system that would award new contributors with extra points for their first N (let's say 5) questions, would be way more satisfying for all. They would probably feel more welcome and we all know that people learn better from an reward perspective than from a punishment perspective.

And we can set objective rules for what a good question is. Sample data, query attempt, create table syntax and so on.

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: We already award good questions via upvotes and bounties. Also I think it is essential to punish bad questions, so we can keep a dwindling amount of quality here.

Comment: If you encounter sarcasm, flag it.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Thanks for pointing that out. I actually did search for "awarding new contributors" and found nothing that was matching my point of view here. As far as your comment goes about the lack of quality of this question itself, I think the community seems to agree with you.  :)

Comment: @SQL_M: yes and no. Voting on meta may be different, especially when it comes to feature requests. Many down-vote the request if they disagree with it, and it's somewhat of a mixed bag here, since DV's also can be given for question quality as well.

Comment: I will say for the record that I like your question's *tone*, in that it does invite discussion, and this is important on meta.

Comment: consider studying discussions in the [meta-tag:welcoming] tag, for example: [Can we make it more obvious to new users that downvotes on the main site are not insults and in fact can help them help themselves?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/366889/839601) and linked to it

Comment: The main problem I think is more that new users do not want to work on their posts at all. They are used to "type question in Google -> Follow link to Stack -> get answer". which, over time, just ends up losing the "Google -> Follow link to" part. These users do not want to ask better questions. They do not want to learn our ways, our intent or our goals. They just want their answer **NAO**

Comment: Weighting upvotes more heavily would feel more welcoming, while removing whatever, "sting" downvotes and other curation does.  It would destroy the minimal barrier already in place for upvoting and comments.  If you're going to make upvotes heavier, downvotes have to be made just as heavy for the same time frame.  Personally, I don't want new users getting banned from their very first question, but I also don't want them to be rewarded for asking a question that we're not going to accept, only to have that reward removed as soon as we delete their off-topic question.

Comment: @SQL_M: "*Thanks for pointing that out. I actually did search for "awarding new contributors" and found nothing that was matching my point of view here.*" Your basic point is to reward new users *more* for asking good questions than equally good questions from other users. Is that a thing we really want to do?

Comment: @NicolBolas Yes, I think the main point here is that new users in general will ask lower quality questions than regs, because they lack some information. Therefor I would indeed argue that they receive more credits for a good question than regs would get.

Comment: A good side-effect of giving users a little rep for their first question: then they have some rep to lose when we downvote it, and can easily distinguish between _first question_ and _second question, first one received multiple downvotes_

Comment: StackOverflow got an award for being in top3 harshest internet communities.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> I feel that new contributors are often treated a bit harsh on SO. We have all seen the 'Hi, welcome to SO. Here's why your question is bad', accompanied with lots of downvotes and in some cases some sarcasm on the side.

There's nothing wrong with a sincere welcoming comment informing a new user why their question is bad. Downvotes are also a good signal that quality is lacking. If you see sarcastic comments, flag them and they'll be deleted. This is something the site has been trying to get under control for a long time now.

> I feel that a system that would award new contributors with extra points for their first N (let's say 5) questions, would be way more satisfying for all. They would probably feel more welcome and we all know that people learn better from an awards perspective than from a punishment perspective.

New users are already rewarded for *good* questions. I don't know if giving them an additional bonus for upvoted questions would help or not, but I don't see any harm either. In order for it to do any good, you'd probably need to notify people that they were awarded the extra bonus and why. (Something along the lines of "You were awarded +2 bonus points because a veteran user found your first question useful!") As you said, there is a benefit to reinforcing good behavior.

> And we can set objective rules for what a good question is. Sample data, query attempt, create table syntax and so on.

[We have those](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), more or less. It's not 100% objective (because that's impossible), but there are a set of guidelines that I think most people follow (somewhat) when voting on questions. New users are shown a lot of guidance before they ever post a question. The real problem is getting them to use any of it.

Comment: You might be right about the sincere welcoming comment. I interpreted them as being negative, but my judgement may be off here. As for the extra points, that would be a great way to bind new contributors to SO.

Comment: One potential problem I see with extra initial reputation is that it would make sympathy and badge votes even more powerful. It's annoying enough seeing a no-effort question receive 5 rep; imagine it getting 8 or 10.

Comment: @TheWanderer I don't think sympathy/badge upvotes are that big a problem, but you could just not apply a bonus to questions that are already negative to sidestep the issue.

Comment: @BilltheLizard I've seen quite a few terrible questions in the Android tag get an almost instant upvote.

Comment: @TheWanderer It's hard to imagine what the motivation for that is.

Comment: @BilltheLizard it's very easy to imagine: people want the vote badge. It's harder to prove or support, though.

Comment: @BilltheLizard also, whatever the motivation, it does happen where a terrible first question receives an upvote (sometimes even two) almost immediately after it's posted, or at least before there's been enough time for someone to actually find, read and downvote it. Not adding the extra positive weight to an already-downvoted question will help in some cases, but not all.

Comment: @TheWanderer I think it will help in the vast majority of cases.