# Why do people comment instead of voting to close?

Tags: discussion, comments, vote-to-close

I am mostly looking at new posts and I noticed what people often write comments instead of voting, e.g.

> Your question is not clear. There are no question marks in your question.

instead of voting "Needs more details or clarity",

> That's broad, can you be more specific?

instead of voting "Needs more focus", etc. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58935380/1997232) is an example.

Why do they not vote straight away? Are they afraid of something? Are they being "nice"?

Comment: related: [Can we make it more obvious to new users that downvotes on the main site are not insults and in fact can help them help themselves?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/366889/839601) (["downvotes are taken so damn personal..."](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253230/839601))

Comment: @gnat, it's not about downvotes, it's about unclear post stays opened, because people instead of voting close just upvote first comment.

Comment: Commenting requires 50 reputation points. Close voting 3000. On top of that, yes, many users do not use their voting privileges as often as possible, which is a shame.

Comment: reason is pretty similar though - some just think than closing is punishment and hesitate because of that. See eg [Rethink “Close Question”](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/391474/839601) "how closing questions work and how they can depress first-time users, maybe we should take a step back..."

Comment: If I see that the OP is involved (they're editing, responding to comments) I forgo that type of curation with the assumption that things are going to work out just fine. If I'm not entirely sure I just leave it open in a tab and check back later to see what happened.

Comment: Is there a reason why you are singling out the users who leave a comment to try and improve the question but not the ones who just upvote those comments?

Comment: @JoeW Perhaps because it's... hard... to single out anonymous users? When someone leaves a comment, you can address them directly because comments are not anonymous.

Comment: @TylerH Sure you can't identify who they are but it is still something that can easily be mentioned as part of the problem since it is harder for them to respond to anything that the op does as a response to the feedback.

Comment: I tend to comment to ask for clarrification, and if I'm ignored (or the OP responds with no additional information to help them), then vote to close; especially with new users that don't know the site as well. Reopen queues are slow and long, so I'd rather vote when the OP is showing no signs of improvement.

Comment: Ask yourself the following question: _If I downvote and/or close a question for reason 'X', how many times do I revisit the question to check if it has been updated so I can retract my downvote/closevote?_ I believe most people use the comment as a wait and see what happens. If a question has been downvoted a lot of times, it is a hard time to recover from that since the downvoters don't revisit it. It would be nice if you could mark a question as "Notify me upon edit".

Answer (score 22):

I do that sometimes, and the main reason is that I can't change my close vote after I've cast it. I can tell the question isn't answerable, but there are a couple of different close reasons that fit, and I want some clarification to help me decide which one to use. If the clarification ends up making the question answerable, or able to be closed as a duplicate, great. If it isn't given fairly quickly, I'll just use my best judgement for the close reason.

However, I don't find either of the comments you gave as examples to be very helpful, and I wouldn't bother leaving a comment like that. I try to be more specific about what's needed to improve the question to what I think would be an answerable state.

Answer (score 9):

With 5 people needing to vote to get question closed it is mostly pointless to vote on questions that are less than clear cut to avoid wasting votes. Unfortunately, this leads to a death spiral - people vote to close less and the bar for "absolutely off-topic" goes higher.

It does not help that close votes are considered hostile actions...

Comment: What's wrong with close votes being hostile? I think that's a good thing. It's a prompt that something needs to change.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe they want to provide some feedback to help the person change and correct the question before taking action against it? You linked to a question that is 24 minutes old as of the time of this answer, so I don't see any reason why the OP won't have time to fix it before people end up voting on the question and never returning after it is fixed.

Is it more important to vote on a question and never return or provide some feedback and possibly return as you get responses to that feedback?

One thing I would ask is why are you just mentioning the people who leave the comment and not the countless others who view the question and only upvote a comment that is saying the question is bad? On the question that you have linked there are many more people who just upvoted an existing comment, but appear to have taken no other action on the question.

Comment: The feedback that *is* being left is essentially the same as the feedback the OP would get from a vote, just hand typed instead of a canned message. And yes, arguably it *is* important to vote.

Comment: @deceze It's a fact that getting a question reopened or getting downvotes removed for an improved question is at least an order of magnitude more difficult than closing a question or getting downvotes in the first place. If someone wants to work with an asker first, we should encourage that. "shoot first and ask questions later" is not a good strategy.

Comment: Casting a close vote doesn't tell OP anything until the question is already closed, at which point it's usually too late to salvage the question. Commenting gives *immediate*, completely customizable feedback, and lets *all* viewers know someone has started engaging with OP to improve the question.

Comment: @TylerH I totally acknowledge the point about magnitudes. I'll offer the fact that many many *many* askers never reply to any feedback as a counter point. What trumps what here…?

Comment: @deceze Yes, and the *easy* recourse for that would be, upon receiving no reply, to vote to close and/or downvote. The point is exactly that, because it's harder to reverse, it should be the last step, not the first. Also keep in mind I am saying this as someone who uses up their 50 close votes almost every day (and would use up 100 close votes if Shog let me).

Comment: @TylerH So you're saying people are required or encouraged to come back again and again to check on progress on each question they visited to close vote after some grace period? And in that time other users should stumble across the unanswerable question and waste their time the same way?

Comment: @deceze No, I'm simply saying if someone wants to engage with someone first to rehabilitate the question rather than throw it in question jail, that should be encouraged. Your comment to Joe seems to discourage it by (IMHO wrongly) conflating the two actions of voting to close and commenting. That's all.

Comment: @TylerH I'll stress this sentence again: *[O]ther users should stumble across the unanswerable question and waste their time [..]?* – There's a reason we close vote. If somebody tries to be kind and help OP personally… yes, sure, more power to them. But by not voting they're not helping declutter the site either.

Comment: @deceze The problem with that is that there are two main categories for close-worthy questions: ones that will never be on-topic unless they are changed to become an entirely different question altogether, and ones that are close-worthy because they don't fit the requirements *right now*--they're a little unclear, or lacking a minimal example, etc. The first kind, sure, we should close silently and move on w/ our lives. But we're talking about the second kind, here. So, yes, *these* kinds of questions probably ought to remain visible to "others"--they could potentially help them w/ some care.

Comment: @deceze I understand in the grand scheme of things that the feedback is the same but on a fresh question, leaving a comment gives the user a chance to fix the question so that it is in a state where it might not get closed. I deffently think there is a difference between leaving a comment on a fresh question instead of voting than an older one.

Comment: @Joe, Tyler: I totally get where you guys are coming from. I'd prefer to help as many people as possible too, and I often do go back to questions I voted on and comment to try to get questions into shape. Anyone who chooses to do that, great. There's still a tension between that and simply trying to handle the onslaught of mostly terrible garbage in an efficient manner. And without voting, it's just getting worse. So… I don't have an ultimate solution to that either.

Comment: @deceze it would help if Shog would implement 3CVs already... and created a test implementation for improved tag-badge closure powers beyond the dupehammer.

Comment: @deceze: I have nothing to add to what Tyler and Joe have said except that it should be fairly easy to triage questions that are likely to be improved and focus the gentler approach on those.

Comment: We do have a triage queue... which is a joke in itself, because [people do not know how to review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/24391499)...

Answer (score -3):

If a question is close, then I'd rather comment on it.  First off, that tells them what additional information we need.  Secondly, it gives them a chance to fix it.  If the question gets closed, its almost impossible to reopen when the asker updates it.

Now if its just nowhere near a good question "How do I write a social media app" or the like, just vote to close.